# Display Coupons while screen locked

Tags: android, locking, android-activity

I want to display deals from website when the screen is locked in an android application.

I succeeded to display the activity when the screen is locked. But while pressing the home key of the device the activity exits. So I want to know exactly how we detect the home button on the device is pressed or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the state of your Activity on the SharedPreferences so in your activities onStop method you can set the variable "running" to false and then on your onResume method set it to true.